# XPATH 2.0 collection() with "?select=" (in eXist-db / XQuery)

Tags: xpath, exist-db, xquery-3.0

Using XPath 2.0 in eXist 4.4 and XQuery.

I have a series of documents in eXist-db directory `/db/apps/deheresi/data` which I want to retrieve with `collection()`, but using a wildcard or predicate to filter specifically-named documents.

For example, I'd like to get the documents that begin with `ABC` and end with `.xml`. I thought a wildcard like so `?select=ABC*.xml` would work, but it's not returning the expected results.

```
collection("/db/apps/deheresi/data?select=ABC*.xml")
```

I also tried to apply a combination of `starts-with` and `ends-with` but to no success. I am no doubt overlooking something simple here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to tell us which environment you use XPath 2.0 with, the use of the `collection` function is not standardized, I am rather sure Saxon 9 for instance supports your attempt of `collection("file:///db/apps/deheresi/data?select=ABC*.xml")` if `/db/apps/deheresi/data` is the path to a directory but other processors or environments like XML data bases might have very different conventions to use the `collection` function.

Comment: Ah, will this is in eXist-db 4.4 and XQuery 3.1. I will update the post accordingly.

Comment: As Martin says, the `select=*.xml` convention is peculiar to Saxon though I believe it has been copied by some other XQuery implementations. But it's not defined in the W3C specs so you can't expect every processor to support it.

Comment: @MichaelKay Are there other XPATH functions or predicate tricks to filter collections on the document name that I might try?

Comment: You could try using `uri-collection()` which gives you a list of all the URIs, and then filter this yourself before retrieving the documents. But I've no idea if that works, or is the best solution, in the context of eXist-db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this in exist

```
xquery version "3.1";
(: get document names :)
 let $doc-names := for $n in collection('/db/apps/deheresi/data')
 return
    util:document-name($n)

(: apply filter :)
 for $f in $doc-names[matches(., '^ABC.*\.xml$')]
 return
  $f
```

Comment: Indeed, I did something similar...I was just hoping there was a way do to it without a `for`.

Comment: another way (without for) `xmldb:get-child-resources('/db/apps/deheresi/data')[matches(., '^ABC.*\.xml$')]`